# Problems downcasting a hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, casting

I'm handling a problem in downcasting a query.uniqueResult() using hibernate. I have 2 classes:
- UserBean
- UserLogin

In the first one I have the mapping of all my table fields as well as all the methods to deal with data. The second one, instead, represents only some user data that will be stored in the user session.

At certain point in my login method, I execute the query and I get 1 row (I already checked if the query is really returning some result). The point is that I cannot downcast from Object type (that is the query.uniqueResult() type) to the UserLogin type.

Does someone know which could be the problem?

Thanks a lot!

This is the login method:

```
public UserLogin login(String email, String password){

    Session session = iniHibernate();
    UserLogin userLogin = null;

    try{
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = session.createQuery("select email, name from "
                + "UserBean u where u.email = :user_email and "
                + "u.password = :user_password");
        query.setString("user_email", email);
        query.setString("user_password",password);            

        userLogin = (UserLogin) query.uniqueResult();

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return userLogin;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation of [Query.uniqueResults](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#uniqueResult%28%29):

> Convenience method to return a single
>   instance that matches the query, or
>   null if the query returns no results.

The reason why it doesn't work is because your returning an array of Strings not the `UserBean` which I assume is mapped to `UserLogin`.

Try doing this:

```
(String[])query.uniqueResult();
```

or changing your query to get the object:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("select u from "
            + "UserBean u where u.email = :user_email and "
            + "u.password = :user_password");
```

That should get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mohamed. I implemented your suggestion 

(String[] queryResult = (String[])query.uniqueResult();) 

but I'm still obtaining the following error (I kept the query to only name & email fields):

- INFO: java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;

Comment: If you change it to Object[] what is the type for it?

Comment: Mohamed at the end I changed the query to the UserBean object (as you suggested) and then I created an userLogin object from the UserBean data. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MohamedMansour The individual "component types" of the array are Strings, but the array itself is always an Object[].  Another option keeping the scalar SQL results (smaller JDBC ResultSet size) while still dealing with OO rep in memory is what Hibernate calls a "dynamic instantiation query"; `select new UserNameAndEmailBean( u.email, u.name) from UserBean u ...`.  There instead of List<Object[]> you'd get back List<UserNameAndEmailBean>.  UserNameAndEmailBean is any class (does not have to be mapped); must have a matching constructor (here String,String).

Answer (score 3):

I have resolved it by adding entity type to the query object as:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString).addEntity(Foo.class);
Foo foo = query.uniqueResult();
```

This will work perfectly no need to worry for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Entity, you can use

```
Query query = session.createQuery(queryString);
Object[] obj= query.uniqueResult();
```

This works well for me.