# How to assign the query result to the user id

Tags: java, hibernate

How to assign the query result to the user id.

My code is here

**KullaniciBean.java**

```
    public String girisKontrol(){

    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.getTransaction();

    List<Kullanici> list = session.createSQLQuery("select * from kullanici where kadi='" + kullanici.getKadi() + "' and ksifre='" + kullanici.getKsifre() + "'").list();
    SQLQuery kuid = session.createSQLQuery("select id from kullanici where kadi='" + kullanici.getKadi() + "' and ksifre='" + kullanici.getKsifre() + "'");

    kullanici.setId(kuid); //PROBLEM line

   if (list.size()>0){
       return "gorevSayfasi";
   }else {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "user not found", ""));
    }
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    return null;
    }
```

**kullanici.java**

```
 public class Kullanici  implements java.io.Serializable {

 private Integer id;
 private String kadi;
 private Integer ksifre;
 private Set gorevs = new HashSet(0);
 private Set kullanicirols = new HashSet(0);

public Kullanici() {
}

public Kullanici(String kadi, Integer ksifre, Set gorevs, Set kullanicirols) {
   this.kadi = kadi;
   this.ksifre = ksifre;
   this.gorevs = gorevs;
   this.kullanicirols = kullanicirols;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getKadi() {
    return this.kadi;
}

public void setKadi(String kadi) {
    this.kadi = kadi;
}
public Integer getKsifre() {
    return this.ksifre;
}
```

**gorevSayfasi.xhtml**

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
                 <h:outputText value="id"/>
                 <h:inputText value="#{kullaniciBean.kullanici.id}"/>//PROBLEM line


                <h:outputText value="Kullanici Adi"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{kullaniciBean.kullanici.kadi}"/>

                <h:outputText value="Sifre"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{kullaniciBean.kullanici.ksifre}"/> 
</h:panelGrid>
```

I want to assign the query result to the `kullanici.id` (online user id). And I dont know how can I it. It is my first Java Hibernate project can you help me please about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String girisKontrol(){

SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
Session session = factory.openSession();
session.getTransaction();

List<Kullanici> list = session.createSQLQuery("select * from kullanici where kadi='" + kullanici.getKadi() + "' and ksifre='" + kullanici.getKsifre() + "'").list();
Query kuid = session.createQuery("select id from kullanici where kadi='" + kullanici.getKadi() + "' and ksifre='" + kullanici.getKsifre() + "'");


//-----------------solution------------------------
kullanici.setId((Integer) kuid.uniqueResult());

if (list.size()>0){
   return "gorevSayfasi";
}else {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "user not found", ""));
 }
  session.beginTransaction();
  session.getTransaction().commit();
  session.close();
  return null;
}
```

Make sure that the query returns only a single result. If there more than one matching result it will throw `NonUniqueResultException`. (Therefore `query.setMaxResults(1);` would be more appropriate).

Comment: List<Kullanici> list = session.createSQLQuery = is just control  and Query kuid = session.createQuery is return a single resut for example: 1 and i want to use this as a kullanici.id

Comment: do you have a controller? to set the value in view

Comment: kullanici.setId((Integer) kuid.uniqueResult()); symbol: method uniqueResult()  location: variable kuid of type List<Kullanici>   i get this error

Comment: gorev.setAciklama(gorev.getAciklama());
        gorev.setTarih(gorev.getTarih());
        gorev.setDurum(gorev.getDurum());
        session.save(gorev);   i have this and i can add that values to my table except id

Comment: if you use you own entity type then use like this `Entity object = (Entity) query.uniqueResult();`

Comment: In database make you `id` as a `primary key autoincrement`, then add that values to you table except id.

Comment: @Mustafa hopefully this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5385263/4457657   help you to solve error

Comment: I've already done this and i can add other values i can not add the online user id to other table.(kullaniciid=online user id)

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLQuery kuid = session.createSQLQuery("select id from kullanici where kadi='" + kullanici.getKadi() + "' and ksifre='" + kullanici.getKsifre() + "'");
    List<Kullanici> list = kuid.list();
    kullanici.setId((Integer) kuid.uniqueResult());
```

i solved ty  Salim Ahmed.